# how to convert 5.5 to 5.0 in java

Tags: java

I know it may sound stupid. But I don't know how to convert 5.5 into 5.0.

What I have done is:

```
int expiry = month2 + month1;
int expiry1 = expiry;
int sum = 0;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");
df.format(expiry);
if (expiry > 12) {
    expiry = (expiry / 12);

    sum = ((expiry1 - (expiry * 12)) - 1);
    System.out.println(sum);
    month3 = sum;
    year1 = (year1 + expiry);

}
```

If we consider if condition whenever value of expiry is for example 30, it gives output as 3 because of decimals but i want answer as 2. I tried using Decimal format but does not work. I tried casting but I failed while trying it (maybe I don't know the correct way of doing it).

I tried using pattern

```
String truncatedValue = String.format("%d", expiry).split("\\.")[0];
```

and then again converting it into integer but this does not work for me.

Comment: why not use [`Math.floor(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-)?

Comment: Or `double d = 5.5; d=(double)(int)d;`, ugly as hell but works

Comment: @Turing85 i guess by using Math.floor(double) 5.5 / 5.6 will get converted into 6.(I dont know whether it is correct or not as i am new in Java) but I want output as 5 in case when value of expiry is 5.5 or 5.6

Comment: @sss, Not correct... `Math.floor()` will always return the nearest integer less than the passed number. So till `5.9`, it will return `5` only.

Comment: @sss I linked the javadoc to the method. Did you even read it?

Comment: @Codebender okay.. I will try it..:)

Comment: Turing85 solution is cleaner and more correct, I'd never use mine in some real code, I was just playing around with datatypes

Comment: @Turing85 where is javadoc? and how to read it?

Comment: @sss go to my first comment, click on `Math.floor(double)`.

Comment: How should this treat `-5.5`? Should it go to `-6.0` or `-5.0`, or are negative numbers not relevant at all?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use `Math.floor`.
Another option is to convert to a `long` or use `Math.round`. Here's an overview of your options to get `x = 5`:

```
// Casting: Discards any decimal places
double a = (long) 5.4;
System.out.println(a); // 5.0

double b = (long) 5.6;
System.out.println(b); // 5.0

double c = (long) -5.4;
System.out.println(c); // -5.0

double d = (long) -5.6;
System.out.println(d); // -5.0

// Math.floor: Rounds towards negative infinity
double e = Math.floor(5.4);
System.out.println(e); // 5.0

double f = Math.floor(5.6);
System.out.println(f); // 5.0

double g = Math.floor(-5.4);
System.out.println(g); // -6.0

double h = Math.floor(-5.6);
System.out.println(h); // -6.0

// Math.round: Rounds towards the closest long
double i = Math.round(5.4);
System.out.println(i); // 5.0

double j = Math.round(5.6);
System.out.println(j); // 6.0

double k = Math.round(-5.4);
System.out.println(k); // -5.0

double l = Math.round(-5.6);
System.out.println(l); // -6.0
```

If you just want to get rid of the decimal places, casting is just fine.

If you want to round to the next smaller value, `Math.floor` is your friend.

If you want to round the way most of us learned it in school, `Math.round` will do.

For future reference, you can assume that basic math operations (like rounding up/down) are implemented in respective libraries, so it doesn't hurt to have a quick search on the topic.